# Android Studio SharedPreferences With Double Crashes and Default Values

Tags: java, android, double, sharedpreferences

So i have some code that I want to Save what I typed in a field so when I start the app it has the numbers (Doubles) from before and when it launched the first time it has the default value of 1 I tried but now my app crashes i tried for the last 3 hours the code here is Converting Double To String and String to Double which i know is not the right way to do it but i dont understand the right way here is the code

```
package me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;

import static me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.R.id.brix;
import static me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.R.id.textView;
import static me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.R.id.textView3;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText milkdone;
private EditText brixdone;
private double milkdone2;
private double brixdone2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    milkdone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.milkliter);
    brixdone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.brix);
    milkdone.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                milkdone2 = Double.parseDouble(milkdone.getText().toString());
                brixdone2 = Double.parseDouble(brixdone.getText().toString());
                double test2 = brixdone2 + milkdone2;
                TextView change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                change.setText(String.valueOf(test2));
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }

    });
    brixdone.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                milkdone2 = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("BrixDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
                brixdone2 = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("MilkDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
                double test2 = brixdone2 + milkdone2;
                TextView change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                change.setText(String.valueOf(brixdone2));
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
    };
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        storeDouble("MilkDone2Saved",milkdone);
        storeDouble("BrixDone2Saved",brixdone);

    }
    public void storeDouble(String d, EditText c){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString(d,String.valueOf(c.getText().toString()));
        editor.apply();
}
public void GetDouble(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

}
```

Comment: please show the actual Exception + Stacktrace when you experience a crash. Makes it easier for us to find your issue and might help you understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You may first check your string values which come from Shared Preferences for if they are in floating format or not , then you can convert them.

```
   String MilkDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("MilkDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone));

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(MilkDone2Saved)){
milkdone2 = Double.parseDouble(MilkDOne2Saved);
}
```

Hope this will help :), by the way please choose better variable names for next times.

Comment: thanks that worked but when i only works the first time then i have to restart the app for it to work

Comment: please try to get sharedPreferences data inside onResume method.

Comment: tried dont change anything and brixdone2 + milkdone2 gives only works the first time and its not the right answer so if like  brixdone2 is 1.2 and milkdone2 is 2.1 it says the answer is 3.2222 and i want it to only use one number and one decimal